# Chart render performance slow at Syncfusion with Blazor and .net8

Tags: blazor, rendering, syncfusion, .net-8.0, syncfusion-chart

I am using Blazor with .NET 8 and have 8 charts on my dashboard. I want a loading/progress bar to be displayed while the charts are loading. I am attempting to achieve this with a variable _isLoaded, which is set to true and false in OnParametersSetAsync. However, the loading bar disappears after the data are fetched from the API, but the dashboard still needs more time to render the charts. How can I either minimize the rendering time or ensure the progress bar disappears when the charts are displayed immediately, without any extra delay?